# Is it fine if I change this adjective from a phrasal idiom into its superlative degree?

Tags: idioms

I‘m just wondering whether changing *good* in **good call** to its superlative degree, that is *best*, still acceptable. I’m a bit hesitant to alter that idiom to be used in my essay because I’m afraid changing so will mess with its essential meaning and might not even be existent in the English lexicon.

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but this is actually pretty common in the negative. If you google, you'll find a lot of examples of "not the best call" and "wasn't the best call" meaning that a decision wasn't good. Can you give us a little more context for your use?

Comment: @1006a “Giving that short film a television series of its own has to be the best call they’ve made thus far.”

Comment: That sounds perfectly idiomatic to me. If you include it in your question it might help answerers give more tailored answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context, it could work. Altering an idiom is a form of wordplay. Depending on your audience, though, it may sound odd or confusing. You can minimize this if it's paired with the idiom in its original form. For example:

> Karen: Good call!
>
> Brian: No, Karen. That wasn't a good call, it was the *best* call!

The (sometimes humorous) subtext of this kind of wordplay is that the idiom is not an idiom at all, but something to be taken literally. By their nature, altered idioms will be much less common than the original idiom. Don't expect to find them in the dictionary. That's the whole point.

#### Examples:

This kind of word play (altering an idiom) is very common in rap lyrics. I just googled "rap lyrics" for an example. Here, in one of the first results, street talk is changed to street, walk:

> I hear you talkin' shit, bro you think you're the heat
> Please bow down to defeat you're barely mince meat
> Stop with the street talk, and start to do the street, walk

Here are some examples from literature, recorded interviews, online articles, and television:

From Janice Kay Johnson's *Patton's Daughters*. "Like two peas in a pod" is changed to "like a lone pea in a pod":

> As it was, by herself in the house Daddy had left jointly to her and her younger sister, Abby, Renee was rattling around like a lone pea in a pod.

[Denzel Washington in an interview with Terry Gross on "Fresh Air"](https://www.npr.org/2016/12/09/504960137/remembering-grant-tinker-mary-tyler-moore-producer-and-nbc-chair), "to make a long story short" becomes "to make a long story long":

> And so to make a long story long, they chose two actors, I believe, from New York, myself and David Morse.

[An article on "Pain in the Arsenal"](https://paininthearsenal.com/2018/05/18/arsenal-frank-lampard-ideal-rejected-one-clear-reason/) starts with "The final straw", and repeats it as "the first straw":

> That, for Arsenal, is the final straw, or, in fact, the first straw in this case, in their assessment of Simeone...

In [Season 5 Episode 19 of "The X Files"](http://www.insidethex.co.uk/transcrp/scrp519.htm), the word play is from "one in a million" to "one in five billion". Note the ellipsis to emphasize that this is an interruption and alteration of the "one in a million" idiom.

> MULDER: Scully, you *have* to believe me. Nobody else on this whole damn planet does or ever will. You’re my one in … five billion.

Comment: 'You can minimize this if it's paired with the idiom in its original form' is a very good point. But for this to be a really good answer, you need to show at least some support for the variation allowed in the idiom (idioms generally resist variation).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's why it's wordplay (idioms resist variation). The idiom itself is well established, so altering it is clever and original. This is so common, I'm surprised you need some examples, but I'll edit the post to include them.

Comment: No. There are well-attested variations with some idioms (up/raise the ante, fit/fill the bill, look/shoot daggers at somebody; a pot/crock (but not jar) of gold, miss the boat/bus (but not train).... With others, as you say, variations would be wordplay. And while the overall concept of varying idioms idiosyncratically probably needs mentioning, giving examples on ELU (which addresses normal _usage_) is off-topic in the same way as discussing DIY candidate words. // In this case, there are many relevant examples of "the best call" on the internet.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can you reference a question on the meta site to support your statement that this (answer) is somehow off topic or not addressing the question? This a common linguistic phenomenon. It produces grammatically correct phrases with defined words. The meaning of these phrases is understood in relation to a fixed expression. I can see how you might want to draw a comparison to malapropisms, malaphors, or neologisms, which are by definition errors or linguistic elements not previously in use, but this phenomenon is both a correct and common way people produce meaning with language.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd add that, both on this and other stack exchange sites, it is reasonable and helpful to answer a question with a general answer as well as a specific answer. Can I do this thing with language? Yes. It's an example of this valid type of thing people do with language all the time.

Comment: '[T]his phenomenon is both a correct and common way people produce meaning with language' is an overstatement. It presumes that productivity (or at least the type under discussion here) is absolute rather than gradable; this has certainly been shown to be in general unjustifiable. //  A 'boat of the desert' for a young camel may be quirky and acceptable in some literary genres, but its acceptability is at best 'Primarily Opinion Based', which is a reason for non-acceptability on ELU. And if you check, you'll find that rap lyrics are rarely considered on-topic here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the correctness depends, quite obviously, on the phrase. The technique is to alter an idiom, producing a correct phrase in an appropriate register for the context. What idiom is A "boat of the desert" referencing?

Comment: ... On the other hand, the number of examples on the internet for 'best call' (usually padded, either by twinning with 'good call', or as say 'the best call of his managerial career') makes this an example where variation seems quite acceptable. But evidence is needed for the particular usage. // I'd have thought that 'ship of the desert' ==> 'boat of the desert' was pretty transparent, though I'd not consider it generally acceptable. // 'The correctness depends, quite obviously, on the phrase' means ...

Comment: that a general statement like 'this [often / sometimes] happens' is inadequate evidence that a particular example is correct.

Comment: The usage here (in the question) is correct and also an example of a common linguistic phenomenon. I'm glad the community and the user who asked the question found my answer to be helpful. You seem to have your own rules or dogma about what an answer should or should not be.

Comment: If someone asks about the acceptability of 'best call', a decent answer will address the idiomaticity (how often it's used) or give a dictionary licensing, rather than just talk about the variability often encountered, both commonly and in novel usages. << Is it fine if I change **this** ...? >>

Comment: Feel free to downvote. You have your own personal rules about what makes a useful answer and should voice them using the tools given to you with the site. I disagree with you.

Comment: 'He's a good egg / bad egg' are idioms showing accepted variation. 'He's the best egg / worst egg' would probably attract a marking down in an essay. Which is the context OP is asking about, not humorous fiction. On the other hand, '[That] has to be the best call they’ve made thus/so far' sounds far more acceptable, and the usage is far more common on the internet. Answers must be specific.

Comment: Answers must be answers. You've made your down vote. Language is produced, understood, and studied by examining abstract patterns.  I happen to think it's just as useful (often more useful) to discuss those patterns than to look for an exact match for a phrase in order to answer a question about how a reader would produce meaning from that phrase. That's just how I was taught when I studied linguistics. I can see where you're coming from, but I still disagree.

Answer (score 0):

**good call** (or bad call)  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call)

```
> informal Used to express approval (or criticism) of a person's
```

> decision or suggestion.

Oxford gives ~ 10 sample sentences.  None vary the two words in the idiom.  You can though consider a very **good call**. etc